# Simple_form with Form Object missing Mapping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2, simple-form-for

I am using simple_form_for

```
<%= simple_form_for( @form_object, url: wizard_path, :method => :put) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :website %>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

However, I am also using a Form Object

```
  class Base
    include ActiveModel::Model
    # Validations
    # Delegations
    # Initializer
   end
```

My issue is that my inputs are not mapping to my database columns, so https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#available-input-types-and-defaults-for-each-column-type

None of these show up ,and can I create custom mappings.

#### How can I allow Simple_form to see my column types and work correctly?

If I check the class of my delegated fields, they seem to show as :string or :integer, etc.

Comment: *"The following table shows the html element you will get for each attribute according to its database definition. These defaults can be changed by specifying the helper method in the column Mapping as the as: option."* from your link. So it appears `<%= f.input :website, as: :string %>` is what you are looking for? Also seems you could use the [`ActiveModel::attribute`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/rails/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods#attribute-instance_method) method to specify the type in Base e.g. `attribute :website, :string`

Comment: I am using `delegate attr.to_sym, "#{attr}=".to_sym, to: model`, not attribute, can I add the type using delegate, if so how? I prefer not to manually set the as: option

Comment: @engineersmnky ^ Any thoughts?

Comment: Try adding `type_for_attribute` and `has_attribute?` to the delegation e.g. `delegate :type_for_attribute, :has_attribute?, to: model` seems like it should work according to the [source code](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb#L581)

Comment: I don't think that's valid, as it would just see :string or :integer as another attribute

Comment: What do you mean? Have you actually tried it? This is exactly how `simple_form` determines the mapping for columns as shown in the source. This has nothing to do with attributes. When `simple_form` calls these methods on your ActiveModel::Model those calls will be delegated to the model and the model will respond accordingly. If you would like more assistance please post more code since TBH this: `delegate attr.to_sym, "#{attr}=".to_sym, to: model` makes no sense in isolation either

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189699/discussion-between-user2012677-and-engineersmnky).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`simple_form` uses 2 methods to determine the input type field mapping from a standard model (`type_for_attribute` and `has_attribute?`). [Source](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb#L581)

Since you are wrapping the model in another layer but still want the inference that `simple_form` provides you just need to delegate these calls to the original model via

```
class Wrapper
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_reader :model
  delegate :type_for_attribute, :has_attribute?, to: :model
  def initialize(model) 
    @model = model
  end
end
```

However if you were not wrapping the model you would need to define these methods yourself such as (using the new rails 5.2 Attribute API)

```
class NonWrapper
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Attributes

  attribute :name, :string

  def type_for_attribute(name)
    self.class.attribute_types[name] 
  end 
  def has_attribute?(name)
    attributes.key?(name.to_s)
  end
end
```

Example

```
a = NonWrapper.new(name: 'engineersmnky') 
a.has_attribute?(:name)
#=> true
a.type_for_attribute(:name)
#=>  => #<ActiveModel::Type::Value:0x00007fffcdeda790 @precision=nil, @scale=nil, @limit=nil>
```

**Note** other additions may be required for a form object like this to work with simple_form. This answer simply explains how to handle the input mapping inference